# Writing data simultaneously on multiple users, by using their id. firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a group collaboration application. I have ran into a problem on how to create groups which contain users in it, users are added to the group by their ids.

now the problem is how can a user who creates a group can write data across multiple users simultaneously . so that a group gets created in their database too, they can collaborate and write data on each others database.

**it's like group chatting where users collaborate with each-other.**

below code shows a user creating a group and trying to write the same group on his friends database, by using an array of user ids.

`.doc([firebase.auth().currentUser.uid, newUser1, NewUser2])`

```
firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection("Groups")
  .doc([firebase.auth().currentUser.uid, newUser1, NewUser2])
  .collection(AllGroups)
  .add({
    UpdatedOn: new Date().toString(),
    CreatedOn: new Date().toString(),
    CreatedBy:firebase.auth().currentUser.name,
    users: [array of users]
    tasks: [{ array of tasks }]
  })
  .then((sucess) => {
    console.log("done");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

but its not working please help me out, or please give me a better solution for it.

[image]

this is the redux call for calling the function

```
    export const CreatingNewGroup = () => {
  let user1id = "***********";
  let user2id = "***********";
  return async (dispatch) => {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("Groups")
      .doc([firebase.auth().currentUser.uid, user1id, user2id])
      .collection("AllGroups")
      .add({
        UpdatedOn: new Date().toString(),
        CreatedOn: new Date().toString(),
        CreatedBy: firebase.auth().currentUser.email,
      })
      .then((sucess) => {
        console.log("done");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
};
```

function is called by this

```
export default function CreatGroups() {
  const Dispatchs = useDispatch();
  return (
    <View>
      <Button
        title="Add"
        onPress={() => Dispatchs(productsActions.CreatingNewGroup())}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: `TypeError: n.split is not a function. (In 'n.split("/")', 'n.split' is undefined)]` but when you remove the brackets and pass, just the object like this
 ` .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid, user1id, user2id)` only one userid is used, no matter which you insert, only one userid can be used, but i need to create a group.
please help.

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of your error here?

Comment: I have added the screen shot of the error.
can it be done by batched Writes, if yes then please answer how.

Comment: Is there any variable called "n" in your code? If yes, can you tell us what this "n" variable is doing in your code?  Also share the full code including usage of "n".

Comment: Your error says that n.split is not a function. So in your code, could you tell us what does n stands for?

Comment: i have shared the code please check it out. there is no variable for function called n

Comment: Checkout this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52547876/javascript-uncaught-typeerror-split-is-not-a-function/52547929) having kind of similar error that you are facing, and let me know if it helps?

Comment: i think the problem is with the square bracket "[]", can you pass an array in .`.doc()`??

Comment: According to this documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#data_types), yes you can.

Comment: So, did you try removing square brackets then? Did it solve your error?

Comment: yes i tried removing the square brackets, but then instead of writing three documents for three users, it writes just one for a single users.

but i want users to collaborate with each other and write each others databases. just like Group chat.

is there any way i can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes from here:

```
.doc([firebase.auth().currentUser.uid, newUser1, NewUser2])
```

The `doc` function expects a string here, not an array of strings. My guess is that it first tries to split the string on `/`, and the array you pass doesn't have a `split` operator.

If you want to write to multiple documents atomically, [use a batch write operation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions).

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, can you please give me an example??

Comment: There are examples in the documentation I linked. If you tried to get that to work yourself and ran into trouble, I recommend posting a new question showing the exact code that you tried with the correct API that I pointed out.